# How to create a TCP listener?

Tags: nginx, server, tcp

I have a websocket app that is running on a Linux server.
in my nginx file it is set up like this:

```
location /messenger/chatrooms/ {
      try_files $uri @proxy_to_ws;
    }


    location @proxy_to_ws {
      proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
```

when I look at the listeners `netstat -ntlp` there is no port 8000, so i get 502 Bad gateway. I have a running version of server in which when I look at the ports I can find :

[image]

and server runs with no issue. I was wondering how should I start tis tcp in the broken server?

Answer (score 0):

You should point your proxy_pass to localhost (or 127.0.0.1) instead:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
```

**0.0.0.0** means that it listens to anything, not just local connections on the same system

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the port can be opened by [following](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html):

```
daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 myproject.asgi:application
```

as it is suggested in the document :

> You should run Daphne inside either a process supervisor (systemd,
> supervisord) or a container orchestration system (kubernetes, nomad)
> to ensure that it gets restarted if needed and to allow you to scale
> the number of processes.